# Get yesterday date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node-mysql

i am try to request date only yesterday but without success...

My query request.

```
SELECT registeredDaySell FROM new_sell WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

My date is organized this way.

> 16 September, 2017

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: You should store dates as dates, not strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff kind `INTERVAL 5 DAY`? can you show me an example?

Comment: the where clause doesn't compare the data to the calculated date, it needs operators such as >=

Comment: (probably) your main problem is that you're not actually specifying a column in your `where` clause... 
How about
`WHERE name_of_date_column >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` ?

Comment: @trs my back end process `SELECT registeredDaySell FROM new_sell WHERE registeredDaySell >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)` but she's just returning it in my json `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT producFinalPrice 
FROM new_sell
WHERE WEEK (date) = WEEK( current_date ) - 1
```

Comment: `Uncaught Exception: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'date' in 'where clause'` I must fill out with my producFinalPrice in `(date) =`?

Answer (score 1):

subdate(now(),1) will return yesterdays timestamp 
The below code will select all rows with yesterday's timestamp from employee_login page

```
Select * FROM `employee_login` WHERE `dattime` <= subdate(now(),1) AND `dattime` > subdate(now(),2)
```

The below code will display yesterday's timestamp

```
Select subdate(now(),1) ,subdate(now(),2))
```

This will give

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon mentioned, you should consider storing your dates either in some date type column, or possibly as a UNIX timestamp (seconds since the epoch).  A possible workaround here would be to use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert your string dates to bona fide dates on the fly.

```
SELECT
    producFinalPrice
FROM new_sell
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%d %M, %Y') = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This assumes that `date_col` is the name of the column in your table which contains string dates.

Comment: i give error of syntax definition `Uncaught Exception: SyntaxError: ../server/index.js: Unexpected token` this my router get `router.get('/sell/home-card-last-sell-yesterday', function (req, res) {
  connection.query('SELECT producFinalPrice FROM new_sell WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%d %M, %Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)',
    function (err, lastSellYesterdayCardHome, fields) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      res.send(lastSellYesterdayCardHome);
    }
  );
});`

Comment: @GabrielCorrea There are unescaped single quotes in your string, that won't work.  Try wrapping the entire query in _double_ quotes, e.g. `connection.query("YOUR QUERY HERE")`

Comment: i must change `date_col` to my `producFinalPrice`?

Comment: i change to double quotes but given error in column `ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'date_col' in 'where clause'`

Comment: @GabrielCorrea I don't know your schema.  Replace `date_col` with the name of the column in your table which stores the dates for each record.

Comment: i am not storage data to current-time-stamp my date record in data picker to my form send date to my table in sql. my back end process request but my response json is `[]`

Comment: Update your question with what query you are actually running.

Comment: already update replace `producFinalPrice` to `registeredDaySell`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT producFinalPrice FROM new_sell 
WHERE where date >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
   and date < convert(date, GETDATE())
```

-1 equates to "today" minus 1 day. You can change that number to get the number of days that you want to go back if further than 1.

Comment: `CONVERT` is a SQL Server function, not a MySQL function.